# ANTLR Error Recovery Causing a NullPointerException in Java

Tags: java, parsing, error-handling, antlr, grammar

I have an ANTLR Grammar that is in the form:

```
A - B: more,things
```

However sometimes, either A or B can be missing such as:

```
  - B: more, things           //Skip
A -  : some, other, things    //Skip
C - D: yet, more, things      //Read this one and following
E - F: things
```

I want ANTLR to skip over those lines (where either side of - is missing) and continue processing the rest.

Basically, something like that

```
  - B: more, things {if (!hasBothParts()) { continueAtNextLine();} };
```

From the book, I provided a @rulecatch and this catch after my appropriate Parser block:

```
catch[RecognitionException re]{
  reportError(re);
  consumeUntil(input, NEWLINE);
  input.consume();
}
```

---

**EDIT 2** - I tried doing this instead:

```
while (input.LA(1) != 6){
  input.consume();
}
```

This worked as expected. 6 is the token identifier for "NEWLINE" for me. I don't know how to do a comparison like input.LA(1) != "\n" or something similar. I know it's not correct to do it this way, I am just experimenting. If you know the right way, please tell me! :)

But this works, unlike the first loop. I suspect consumeUntil is perhaps not seeing the NEWLINE on channel Hidden.

The NullPointer seems to be caused by the input fast-forwarding to EOF, and hence, the tree grammar is hitting a Null when it's doing input.LT(1).

---

However, in doing so, I get a NullPointerException in my tree grammar:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.antlr.runtime.tree.BaseTreeAdaptor.isNil(BaseTreeAdaptor.java:70)
at org.antlr.runtime.tree.CommonTreeNodeStream.nextElement(CommonTreeNodeStream.java:93)
at org.antlr.runtime.misc.LookaheadStream.fill(LookaheadStream.java:94)
at org.antlr.runtime.misc.LookaheadStream.sync(LookaheadStream.java:88)
at org.antlr.runtime.misc.LookaheadStream.LT(LookaheadStream.java:119)
....
```

The behavior I want is for the parser to skip over the lines missing components and proceed with the remaining lines. The tree parser should not be a problem, I assume?

The ANTLR book does not mention anything regarding this issue.

Also, I think the [ANTLR Error Recovery](http://www.antlr.org/blog/antlr3/error.handling.tml) mentions something along those lines but the solution provided is fairly complex/ugly and dates back to 2004. So, is there a better way of doing this relatively simple thing in ANTLR?

Thank you.

**EDIT** If this helps, the error was caused by this line in the generated tree grammar:

```
retval.start = input.LT(1);
```

Which is, I assume, being called with nothing. I.e. LT(1) is returning Null, since it skipped over.

Comment: Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates this exception?

Comment: Afraid I can't do that. The code is rather long and nested. The grammar itself works fine if there's no error correcting code, but I don't want it to break on the first line of this simple error. I just want it to skip over and continue.

Comment: I found this: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Custom+Syntax+Error+Recovery. I'll give this a shot and see if it works better.

Comment: Above doesn't work. I tried something else. Please see EDIT #2. That works, somewhat.